# Why will "0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w" display on screen in csh

Tags: csh

friends, I don't know why "0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w" (and many lines like this) will display when I run some C shell script, but not when some others run. And I never encountered with this problem before, which won't affect my results of my program.

I think there are some problems in the following codes after I tried to debugged and searched, but I do not know what the potential problem exactly is.

```
set time = `saclst KZDATE f $file61 | awk '{print $2}'`

set yea61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $1}'`

set mon61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $2}'`

set day61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $3}'`

set time = `saclst KZTIME f $file61 | awk '{print $2}'`

set hou61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $1}'`

set min61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $2}'`

set sec61 = `echo "$time" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {printf "%5.2f", $3}'`
```

And the standard output to terminal is like the following:

[image: And the standard output to terminal is like the following:]

Comment: Welcome to U&L. This is likely to be related to application `pandamp.csh` you are testing. missing data ? As is not a unix/linux problem.

Comment: I have solved that by another fella. That is due to "set time" statement....!_!

Comment: Questions about Bourne Again shell scripts are not considered to be not Unix/Linux problems here.  It seems arbitrary and wrong for questions about scripts for other Unix shells to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your C shell script you are assuming that you can just employ a variable named `time` as a script variable for your own purposes.  This is not the case.  This variable has special semantics, as explained in the C shell manual.  Employ it as if it were an arbitrary variable that you could just use, and you potentially trigger those side-effects, which are exactly as you are seeing.

Comment: yes, it is due to my "set time = ..."